# Gazebo 1.9 - Fatal error: pcl/conversions.h: No such file or directory

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-1.9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, I have a problem with compilation, fatal error: pcl/conversions.h: No such file or directory.
My error: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6017109

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3608/gazebo-1.9---fatal-error:-pcl/conversions.h:-no-such-file-or-directory./) by [EduardoMaciel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/270/eduardomaciel/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I'm not not working with ros hydro, so i can't be sure how to fix this.
normaly this dependencies should be installed with the rosdep call....

But you could try to install the ros pcl packages for hydro manually

if you use ubuntu you could try

`sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-pcl-conversions` (which probably contains your missing file...)
in this case it might be usefull to install the other `ros-hydro-pcl-*` packages to.

or if you prefer building from source you could take a look here:

[RosWiki PCL](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl)

I hope this can help you

Greetings,

Benjamin

---

Originally posted by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) with karma: 881 on 2013-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EduardoMaciel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/270/eduardomaciel/) on 2013-07-17**:
Hi evilBiber, I will go try install the package, thank a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

`pcl/conversions.h` is part of PCL, but you need PCL version 1.7 to build against this.

There is a hydro package for PCL 1.7.0-rc2 called `ros-hydro-pcl`. If you install/upgrade that package (`sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-pcl`) it should fix your problem.

The `pcl_conversions` package, which the `gazebo_ros_pkgs` depends on now has a versioned dependency on PCL, so this shouldn't happen in the future:

https://github.com/ros-perception/pcl_conversions/commit/b4071f4aa65e9a32908b2dacbdc8e15362d1209b#L1R23

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/425/william/) with karma: 48 on 2013-07-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EduardoMaciel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/270/eduardomaciel/) on 2013-07-17**:
Hi William, I will go try install the package, thank a lot.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/18/joq/) on 2013-07-18**:
We need some way to maintain code that works with both PCL 1.7 and the earlier versions: https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/issues/26

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/18/joq/) on 2013-07-18**:
We need some way to maintain code that works with both PCL 1.7 and the earlier versions: https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/issues/26

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/904/moda/) on 2014-07-21**:
Sorry, i'm not using gazebo, and I am in groovy , ubuntu 12.04
I have the very same error.
And when I launch sudo apt -get ros-groovy-pcl the error remain
Can you please help me